# "You may only add a comment every 30 seconds" comes up, even if the comment didn't post sucessfully

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Writing less than 15 characters in a comment triggers the 30 second protection.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23643/writing-less-than-15-characters-in-a-comment-triggers-the-30-second-protection)

If you you attempt to add a comment, and the comment fails to add (for instance, if it is less than 15 chars); then the system doesn't let you from resubmit (after fixing the fault, of course) for 30 seconds.

Comment: FYI original question this duplicates is here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103037/comments-that-fail-to-post-start-the-you-can-only-comment-every-5-seconds-time