# When I post a comment to an answer and refer to two people, it throws an error

Tags: support, comments

I tried referring to 2 members by placing the '@' symbol before their names in a comment. I removed one of the '@' symbols and was able to post the comment.

I then clicked on 'Edit Comment' and tried adding the '@' symbol, but this time around I got an error message that said "You may only edit a comment every 5 seconds".

I think this error message shouldn't have been shown and is incorrect since this was my first edit of the comment.

**Edit:** This error appears even if the comment is new. To summarize: if I post a comment referring to two members, I get the error as shown [here](http://img6.imageshack.us/img6/4814/bugstackoverflow.png).

I'm running Chrome 14.0.xxx.xxx on Ubuntu 11.04.

Comment: Your bug report is kind of confusing. Are you reporting that the error message is incorrect ("cannot post within 5 seconds" instead of "cannot @-address more than one person") when you try to edit the second @ back in?

Comment: @AnnaLear: That is exactly what I'm saying. I didn't know that there was a restriction placed on the number of people you could tag in a comment. That's the reason I don't mention that in the problem description. I knew of that restriction only from the linked purportedly duplicate bug report. Thank you for paying attention to the question. Really appreciate it.

Comment: @user183037 You should have been notified of the restriction when trying to post a comment with more than one @ in it.

Comment: @AnnaLear: I was not.

Comment: I've closed the older question as a duplicate of *this* one, and modified this one to match the edits @AnnaLear made to the other. Better?

Comment: Dori: I really don't mind which one is closed/kept opened as long as the issue is addressed. But there were several comments exchanged with @waiwai933 that aren't present in either thread now. Though it specifically didn't have much to do with the bug report at hand, it definitely reflected the general attitude of trigger-happy duplicate markers. If you removed them to keep the discussion on topic, I can live with that.

Comment: @Dori can't you clear the Close flags? It's really confusing..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Comments that fail to post start the "You can only comment every 15 seconds" timer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103037/comments-that-fail-to-post-start-the-you-can-only-comment-every-15-seconds-time)

Comment: @user183037 - With only one question open, those comments were no longer relevant to the actual issue. I removed them to keep them from being a distraction.

Comment: @Shadow - If there's a way for me to do that, I've never found it.

Comment: @Lance - We've been through this; it's a different issue entirely.

Comment: @Dori, actually I think it's the same issue, just maybe a different variant (5 vs 15 seconds, editing vs posting (though editing is still the cause)).

Comment: @Lance - Then you haven't read the entire page; below, he says he's getting the editing error **even when he has not edited anything.**

Comment: @Dori, His question specifically mentions editing, but it doesn't actually matter, the `erroneous error message` is the same type as the other question.  I don't really care if this question gets closed or stays open, I just didn't agree with the duplicate others were choosing.

Comment: @Lance - As I said, "read the entire page"—particularly, his comment below that says "I wasn't editing it, I was posting it for the first time."

Comment: @Dori Closing a question and reopening will "clear" close votes, although I bet it's more of a side-effect than intended usage of the binding votes.

Comment: @Anna - Yeah, I know about that hack; I just wish there was an actual non-hacky way to clear them.

Comment: @LanceRoberts: It it indeed a different issue as Dori said (I just got that error message again when I tried to reference Dori). The message I get is not that only one user can be notified, it's that only 1 comment can be posted every 5 seconds.

Comment: @user183037, yes, and the other question isn't really about the double-`@ issue either, it's all about the error messages for timing on comments, just like this one.  The real issue if you go back even farther, is the race condition that SE setup for comment timing.

Comment: @LanceRoberts: Sigh. It is not. I don't know how else I can explain this. The issue is definitely about the double '@'.

Comment: Can't anybody else reproduce this error? Exact steps to reproduce this bug would be to reply to this comment and try to tag 2 users using the '@' symbol.

Comment: @user183037 I can't reproduce it (Chrome whatever-the-latest-stable-version-is, Windows 7). I get the expected "only one user can be notified" error.

Comment: @AnnaLear: This comment is being posted from Firefox and it has the same issue. I'll try and find a Windows PC to see if I can reproduce the issue on that. So Chrome 14 and Firefox 6.0.2 on Ubuntu 11.04 have this issue - if anybody can try this on Ubuntu 11.04, I'd very much appreciate it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To expand/clarify what's happening, I did some experimenting and it looks like there are two things going on:

1. You cannot @-address two people in the same comment. When you try to do so, you will see the following error:

   [image: screenshot]
2. You can only post one comment every 5 seconds. An comment edit appears to count as posting a comment. In that sense, your first question appears to have correctly been closed as a duplicate of [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103037/comments-that-fail-to-post-start-the-you-can-only-comment-every-5-seconds-timer). It is also about the "you can only post one comment every 5 seconds" error being shown erroneously in a similar scenario.

The time between your first comment and your second comment doesn't matter here. The reason you saw this message is because there was less than 5 seconds between you posting the second comment and editing it. If you wait longer before editing, you should see the "only one additional @user" pop-up if you try to add a second @ into the comment.

It seems, though, that I can edit comments even within the 5-second window if there are no issues with the edit that would normally show an error.

So, it looks like your bug here is that the "only one additional @user can be notified" but "you can only edit a comment every 5 seconds" message is shown instead.

Comment: Although personally I think the fact that the rate limiting comes first is `status-bydesign`.

Comment: "So, it looks like your bug here is that the "only one additional @user can be notified" but "you can only edit a comment every 5 seconds" message is shown instead." - that is exactly what's happening. In fact, in one of the comments to the question above, I addressed the comment to Dori and referred to waiwai in the text. When I hit submit, it gave me the rate limiting error again. Note that it was a comment after a good hour or so from my previous comment. Also, I wasn't editing it, I was posting it for the first time. I took a screenshot this time, I don't know how useful that is though.

Comment: @user183037 You might as well post the screenshot for good measure. Also, could you indicate your browser and operating system information?

Comment: The 5/15 second comment editing bug is referenced here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103037/comments-that-fail-to-post-start-the-you-can-only-comment-every-15-seconds-time

Comment: @TimStone: Here you go: http://img6.imageshack.us/img6/4814/bugstackoverflow.png (notice the 2 '@' in the comment text). That comment wasn't an edit, it was a new one. Bug report updated to include OS and browser information.

Comment: @user183037 In your screenshot, what's the red icon in the right of the omnibar? Also, when you submit the comment, are you pressing enter in the text field, tabbing to the comment button and pressing enter, or clicking the comment button with your mouse? I have a guess as to what the issue is, although I'm at a loss to explain why it would be happening.

Comment: @TimStone: That's Adblock Plus. I don't think it's the reason because I'm getting error message 1 instead of error message 2. If I didn't get either, I would have faulted it :) I usually simply hit enter to post the comment.

Comment: @user183037 Are you able to reproduce this every time you submit a new comment containing two `@names`? If so, could you open the Chrome Developer Tools before you do and grab a screenshot of the requests made during the submit?

Comment: @TimStone: http://img269.imageshack.us/img269/1781/bugstackoverflow2.jpg

Comment: @user183037 Hm...weird. I'm out of ideas then, since I'm unable to reproduce this myself. Hopefully a dev can shed some light on what's going on.

Comment: @Tim, what I can't understand at all: on Meta.SO it should say _15_ seconds, not 5.

Comment: @HendrikVogt Oddly, it seems to be alternating between 5 and 15 for me (or I'm hallucinating).

Comment: @HendrikVogt: It's always showed me 5 seconds.

Comment: @TimStone: hehe, that's okay, thanks for trying :)

Comment: @Tim: Here on Meta it's 15 seconds for comment _submissions_, 5 seconds for _edits_.

Comment: @HendrikVogt Right, [but...](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Tov9F.png).

Comment: @Tim: Very strange indeed. I'm getting this now, too ...

Comment: @Tim: At the moment I get 5 seconds _consistently_. Maybe they changed this? Yesterday I got 15 seconds consistently ...

Comment: This issue has now been fixed - I've marked @AnnaLear's response as the accepted answer because from my perspective she contributed most to the issue. Thanks for that :)

It would have been nice for somebody from SO to have updated this thread notifying that the bug had been fixed; but as long as it was fixed, it's all good :)