# "live" and on submit comment length counters have different logic in @mentions

Tags: bug, stack-overflow, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do I keep getting told I posted less than 15 characters when I posted more than 15?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110305/why-do-i-keep-getting-told-i-posted-less-than-15-characters-when-i-posted-more-t)

I've noticed a bug:

When you type a comment, live text length counter counts user name mentioning, e.g. `@xyz`, as proper comment text, so allows the comment to submit thus starts count the comment length itself:

> 585 characters left

But on submit yields:

> Comments must be at least 15 characters in length.

Comment: Just to be sure: so this only happens when [the system removes `@mentions`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97098/eeeeek-what-happened-to-my-salutation/97099#97099) that have no effect? Then please add that to the title.