# Why do rejected comments still count towards the 1 comment per 15 sec limit?

Tags: discussion, bug, comments, rate-limiting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Comments that fail to post start the “You can only comment every 5 seconds” timer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103037/comments-that-fail-to-post-start-the-you-can-only-comment-every-5-seconds-time)

I just tried to post a comment, In this comment I used multiple @user mentions. When I pressed the add comment button I was notified that only 1 user may be mentioned in this way per comment. I find this strange, but I don't have a problem with it. So I erased all but one mention and hit the add comment button again. This time I got the pop-up telling me that I can only post 1 comment every 15 seconds.

My question is why did my rejected comment (for multiple @mentions, but I assume it will work this way if it is rejected for any other reason too) count towards my 1 per 15 seconds when it didn't actually get posted?

Comment: [Now fixed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103037/comments-that-fail-to-post-start-the-you-can-only-comment-every-5-seconds-timer).