# Comment time-out issue

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, rate-limiting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Comments that fail to post start the “You can only comment every 5 seconds” timer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103037/comments-that-fail-to-post-start-the-you-can-only-comment-every-5-seconds-time)

Not a big issue, just something I noticed.

I tried to upvote a comment, but I got the message the comment was deleted.

Right after that I tried to upvote another comment and I got the 5 seconds timeout message.

But I didn't get the chance to vote on the first one so why would the 5 seconds timeout message appear?

Comment: Expected behavior.  The comment rate limiter is just devoid of any sign of intelligence.  Any action starts the timer.  The one that gets me every time is deleting my comment to upvote somebody else's.

Answer (score 1):

The throttle is in place before checking the date of the previous vote (actually, that doesn't happen, it's the throttle mechanism *itself* preventing that).  The throttle is on the *request* to vote, which you made two of inside 5 seconds, tripping the throttle as intended.

Comment: No it isn't expected behavior. It might be by-design, but I didn't expect it...

Comment: @PeeHaa Should be fixed now, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103037/comments-that-fail-to-post-start-the-you-can-only-comment-every-5-seconds-time/