# Attempting to post a < 15 char comment triggers the 'wait' timer

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Writing less than 15 characters in a comment triggers the 30 second protection.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23643/writing-less-than-15-characters-in-a-comment-triggers-the-30-second-protection)

I notice a change has been made to how long comments can be. Again.

I used to just pad out my comments to 15 chars with spaces, and when the new limit was introduced, I then padded it out to 15 characters with spaces and then put a full stop on the end (period for those in NA).

Now when I do that it seems to disallow this. Ok fine. But when I fixed it to actually make it 15 characters for real, it told me I couldn't post a comment for 25 seconds and the counter was reset.

**The counter should not be reset unless the comment was actually posted.** Now I have to wait 25 seconds just to see if my new format has been accepted (well actually more like 90 seconds cos I keep hitting the button at about 23 seconds because I'm impatient)

[alt text http://www.41085.org/lessthan15.png](http://www.41085.org/lessthan15.png)

Comment: Damnit, how come I can never, ever, ever, find the dupes of anything I post on here. On google, or the built-in search. Blaaahhhhh.

Comment: But yours has freehand circles, so it's the new and improved version...

Comment: Woo. +1 Freehand Circles to me!

Answer (score -1):

I agree. (I don't think there is really a better 'answer' to this)