# Making user wait after rejecting a comment as too short is obnoxious

Tags: bug

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Writing less than 15 characters in a comment triggers the 30 second protection](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23643/writing-less-than-15-characters-in-a-comment-triggers-the-30-second-protection)

I tried to submit a comment that was 14 characters long.  It was rejected - fine; no complaint.  I added some extra characters, and then got told you cannot submit a comment more than once every 15 seconds.  Sorry: *that* is a usability bug.  The timer should only be started after successfully submitting a comment.

Comment: This is basically [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36035/attempting-to-post-a-15-char-comment-triggers-the-wait-timer) and [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23643/writing-less-than-15-characters-in-a-comment-triggers-the-30-second-protection) all over again, only with the current timer length.

Comment: Yes - it is the same issue; it is still a bug that hasn't been fixed, for all the previous 'status-by-design' answers.  The previous incarnations are from 2009 and 2010.  We can still flag this as 'hostile behaviour by SO/SE sites'.  It is frustrating in the extreme when you hit it.

Comment: This is a dupe, but I agree it *is* terribly obnoxious.

Comment: Its even more obnoxious when you're a mod.

Comment: I'd support high rep users being pardoned from the whole experience. Of course, high rep. users are more likely to have convincing arguments on Meta.

Comment: See also: [Comments that fail to post start the timer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103037/comments-that-fail-to-post-start-the-you-can-only-comment-every-5-seconds-timer)

Comment: [Now fixed!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103037/comments-that-fail-to-post-start-the-you-can-only-comment-every-5-seconds-timer)