# The resetting comment timer and double @alerts

Tags: bug, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Comments that fail to post start the "You can only comment every 5 seconds" timer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103037/comments-that-fail-to-post-start-the-you-can-only-comment-every-5-seconds-timer)

The most irritating limit-feature on SO is, by far, the resetting comment timer. The only good thing about it is that I didn't run into it for more than a year, I had almost forgotten about it.

But when I now post a comment like

> @John, like @Pete said ....

there is an error telling me that at most 1 person will be notified and then that resetting timer kicks in. Argggh.

Two requests:

- exclude this error from triggering the timer
- and/or turn this error into a warning and let me post the comment anyway.

For reference, [Writing less than 15 characters in a comment triggers the 30 second protection](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/23643/60761) is a similar report/request. I is marked [by-design] but the issue seems to have been fixed nonetheless.

Comment: It's definitely the most irritating rate-limit on SO.

Comment: It's indeed a dupe, thanks @Tim

Comment: [Now fixed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103037/comments-that-fail-to-post-start-the-you-can-only-comment-every-5-seconds-timer).